# Which is better in terms of performance? To test whether a boolean is true or set it all the times?

Tags: performance, language-agnostic

For example in a very long loop:
(`bool x;`)

To test it always:

```
if (!x) x = true;
```

or just set it to true all the time:

```
x = true;
```

Comment: If the 1st form was faster compilers would always do that.

Comment: Since this is language agnostic keep it mind that, if there are side effects when a bool is assigned, the two versions are not the same. (Examples: overritten setter if bool is a class, changes in concurrency if bool is a semaphor)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The unconditional assignment is, more importantly, easier to read. It is highly unlikely that such code would be executed often enough to affect overall performance of any program.